# Dependencies are installed after the main module? Is there a way to change this?

Tags: python, distutils, setup.py, pypi

I have an setup.py script in my pypi package (PythonQL https://github.com/pythonql/pythonql). I have a post-install hook there, in the setup.py file, that runs after the installation. Sometimes this hook runs after the required dependency is installed, but some people have sent me traces where the hook was running before, breaking everything.

Is it possible to ensure, that the hook is running after all the dependencies are in place?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need dependencies installed *when `setup.py` runs*, you need to specify `setup_requires` dependencies instead. `install_requires` makes no guarantees as to when those are installed, tools installing your package can install those in any order.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Excellent, thank you!!